# How can I determine the closest point to the mouse on a certain shape?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have created a program that restricts the mouse to a certain region based on a black/white bitmap. The program is 100% functional as-is, but uses an inaccurate, albeit fast, algorithm for repositioning the mouse when it strays outside the area.

Currently, when the mouse moves outside the area, basically what happens is this:

1. A line is drawn between a pre-defined static point inside the region and the mouse's new position.
2. The point where that line intersects the edge of the allowed area is found.
3. The mouse is moved to that point.

This works, but only works *perfectly* for a perfect circle with the pre-defined point set in the exact center. Unfortunately, this will never be the case. The application will be used with a variety of rectangles and irregular, amorphous shapes. On such shapes, the point where the line drawn intersects the edge will usually not be the closest point on the shape to the mouse.

I need to create a new algorithm that finds the *closest* point to the mouse's new position on the edge of the allowed area. How can I do this? Preferably the method should be able to execute fast enough to give smooth mouse movement when dragging the mouse against the edge of the area.

( I am doing this in Objective C / Cocoa on OS X 10.7, however, pseudo-code is fine if you don't want to type out code or don't know Objective C / C )

Thanks!

Here is my current algorithm:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "stuff.h"
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>




bool
is_in_area(NSInteger x, NSInteger y, NSBitmapImageRep *mouse_mask){

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSUInteger pixel[4];
    [mouse_mask getPixel:pixel atX:x y:y];

    if(pixel[0]!= 0){
        [pool release];
        return false;
    }
    [pool release];
    return true;
}

CGEventRef 
mouse_filter(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, NSBitmapImageRep *mouse_mask) {


    CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);


    float tX = point.x;
    float tY = point.y;

    if( is_in_area(tX,tY, mouse_mask)){

        // target is inside O.K. area, do nothing
    }else{

    CGPoint target; 

    //point inside restricted region:
    float iX = 600; // inside x
    float iY = 500; // inside y


    // delta to midpoint between iX,iY and tX,tY
    float dX;
    float dY;

    float accuracy = .5; //accuracy to loop until reached

    do {
        dX = (tX-iX)/2;
        dY = (tY-iY)/2;

        if(is_in_area((tX-dX),(tY-dY),mouse_mask)){

            iX += dX;
            iY += dY;
        } else {

            tX -= dX;
            tY -= dY;
        }

    } while (abs(dX)>accuracy || abs(dY)>accuracy);

        target = CGPointMake(roundf(tX), roundf(tY));
        CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(),target);

    }


    return event;
}




int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    stuff *stuff_doer = [[stuff alloc] init];

    NSBitmapImageRep *mouse_mask= [stuff_doer get_mouse_mask]; 


    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;
    CGEventMask event_mask;
    event_mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDragged) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseDragged);

        CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(0);

    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, event_mask, mouse_filter, mouse_mask);

    if (!eventTap) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
    [pool release];

    exit(0);
}
```

[image: example region that might be used (black is the allowed area)]
This is an example of the area bitmap that might be used, the black is the allowed area. 
This shows why converting to a polygon would not be convenient or really even plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- A pretty standard approach to problems of the form: "given a set of 2D points S (in your case, the set of edge points), and a query point P (in your case, mouse position), find the closest point to S in P", is to use a quadtree. They can be seen as a generalization of binary search to 2D. Quadtrees are popular for collision detection in videogames, so you can find a lot of tutorials in google.
- Does the shape change or is it static? In the second case, if memory is not an issue, I'd just precompute the closest edge point for each pixel and put it in a lookup table. (In practice, I'd just using two arrays, one for the x coordinate and another for the y coordinate). Redundant computations can be eliminated by using something along the lines of the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, which in this case has a pretty simple form.

Comment: These seem like really good options. It seems like the lookup table might actually be the easier of the two to implement. I'm not sure what you're talking about with redundant computations and floyd-warshall. I will look into it. since the table would be storing an x and y for the closest point to each of 1.3million pixels, how much space would that take up? My calculations come out to something like 4MB. (11 bits per x, 11 bits per y, 1.3million pixels) Does that seem right?

Answer (score 3):

If a user is moving the mouse pointer and needs to be restricted to a certain region, then I don't think the best solution is to find the closest point inside the region. Instead, what will seem more intuitive to the user is to bring the mouse back into the valid region *at the point it exited it*. This is much easier to implement, provided that you can monitor the mouse position at a sufficiently fast rate.

Now, you may have your reasons to do it the way you want to do it, and I respect that. In that case, I can suggest the following ideas:

1. if you could change the way the valid mouse region is defined from a bitmap to a polygon (a list of 2D points that mark the corners of the area) then the task becomes much simpler. Just find the segment that is closest to the mouse position. As part of that calculation you can get the closest point within that segment, and that is where you want to relocate the mouse pointer.
2. a brute force solution should work also. Start from the current mouse position and work your way outwards. First check the eight pixels around it. Then the 16 around the 8, and so on. Once you find a point that is inside the valid region, record its distance to the current mouse position. Keep going, still looking for pixels that are closer, or until all the pixels in the current outer level have a distance greater than your smallest recorded distance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. The reasoning behind not just moving the point back to the point it exited at is that I need the cursor to smoothly slide along the edges of the area when it is being dragged outwards at an angle. Moving it back to the point it exited at would not allow this. As for your other solutions, 1: I can't redefine it as a polygon, I will include an example shape above to show why. 2: this seems like a good solution, simple to implement, but I wonder if this would take too much overhead? (The mouse can move as far as something like 200 pixels at a time.)

Comment: @JonathonG: overhead will be relative, it depends. If you have to do this calculation once per minute then I'd say it'll be okay. If you do it 30 times a second, then it may be too expensive, but then, I might wonder how can a user take the mouse pointer 200 pixels away so fast. Also, consider that you can create an optimized search that is more efficient than the brute force approach I described, an equivalent of a binary search. It may not give you the best result, but maybe close is good enough for your purposes. Also you may optimize if you know the mouse region is a convex area.

Comment: @Miguel I've added an image to the question of an example area I might be using (the areas are often like this one.) This shows why your answer #1 is not going to work for me. Also, this needs to be done in real time to create smooth mouse movement when dragging against the outside of the shape, which is why overhead is of huge important, 20-30 times per second is probably necessary for smooth mouse movement, though something like 10 would be acceptable. The user can move the cursor 200 pixels away because if the mouse is moving fast enough, the cursor starts to skip further and further.

Comment: @JonathonG: why do you say that the shapes cannot be converted to a polygon? Make a polygon with all the connected edge points, then for each group of three vertices remove the middle one if it falls pretty close to the line between the other two. Keep going like this to reduce the number of vertices to a manageable amount.

Comment: @Miguel While doing that would only sacrifice a small amount of accuracy (in most cases a hardly noticeable amount), it would still sacrifice accuracy. In addition,  the process of converting the various bitmaps that will be used (it can change periodically)into polygons might be just as much trouble as coming up with a solution to finding the closest point on the bitmap. I do, however, see what you are saying.

Comment: @Miguel Although, "storing the 2D points that mark the corners of the area" is the same as just storing the pixels on the edge of the bitmap in an array, if you use enough "edges" for the polygon (one polygon per pixel). This is a highly accurate and most likely more-than-fast-enough solution, I just have to write an algorithm that will map the edge pixels of the shape into an array.

Comment: @JonathonG: Yes, if the number of raw edge points is reasonably low I guess you can just measure the distance to all of them and use the closest.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in details the issue is not very simple (at least if you want efficiency & precision). [Qt Graphics View](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html) is rumored to do a good job on that. Perhaps using it, or glancing at its source code (it is free software) should be helpful?